# Software for modelling 3D graphs(vertices/edges)?

Tags: category-theory, mathematical-modeling

Does anybody know any software that is good for drawing 3D graphs? I mean graphs with vertices and edges, not graphs of functions. I'm looking for something like a draw.io-Solidworks hybrid, where I can use the simple drag and drop functionalities to add nodes/edges but be able to have multiple layers and be able to rotate freely as in Solidworks.

I'm looking for it to draw complex 3D structures and be able to easily navigate/rotate the graph. It's very difficult to illustrate 3D structures in an understandable way using 2D images.

I'm surprised that I can't find any tools for systems modelling or category theory that are well suited for this.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for higher category theory in particular, Jamie Vicary's [Globular](http://globular.science/) is pretty decent and the newer software at [homotopy.io](https://homotopy.io/) are pretty decent. They allow you to build up $n$-dimensional string diagrams frame by frame out of the cells you define and then visualise the overall construction.

They aren't suited for anything that isn't category theory, though.